# Проблема с foreach в PDO php

Tags: php, pdo

Есть такой код:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table','root','12345');

$d = $db->query("SELECT * FROM order");

foreach($d as $d2){
echo $d2['name'];
}
```

Проблема в том, что `foreach` выдает ошибку. 
`print_r($d)` пустой.
 Данные бд (хост, имя бд, пользователь, пароль) указаны верно. Что здесь не хватает?

Answer (score 5):

Здесь не хватает информирования об ошибках.

после строки

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table','root','12345');
```

надо всегда писать вот такую

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

и после этого ПДО начнет сообщать, почему не получилось получить данные.

Answer (score -2):

Не хватает метода [fetch](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Например, можно так извлечь данные:

```
$statement = $db->query('SELECT name FROM order');
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

Также все записи можно извлечь методом [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Ну и добавить выброс исключений при ошибках неплохо бы:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Итого, получится следующий код:

```
try {

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table','root','12345');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $statement = $db->query("SELECT * FROM order");

    foreach ($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $item) {
        echo $item['name'] . <br>;
    }

}
catch (PDOException $e) {  
    // Обработка исключений...
}
```

Comment: Класс `PDOStatement` реализует интерфейс [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.traversable.php). Так что использовать `fetch` вовсе не обязательно

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, спасибо за информацию. Мой ответ получается не совсем верен.

Comment: Писать catch, если не знаешь, что делать внутри, [тоже не стоит](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#exceptions)

Answer (score -3):

Для проверки переменных пользуйтесь `var_dump()` он выводит все типы данных т.к. так как вы получаете объект, вызовите fethAll() и перебирайте в `foreach`

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table','root','12345');

$d = $db->query("SELECT * FROM order");

foreach($d->fethAll() as $d2){
echo $d2['name'];
}
```